# Working with nested lists in Prolog (not SWI-Prolog)

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog. I was asked this question. I cannot be done in SWI-Prolog. Just in prolog base (not sure what to call it). All the answers I found were in SWI-Prolog.

First element of each nested list is either a `0` or a `1`. The second element of each nested list is some integer.

As an example: `[[0 1] [1 2] [1 3] [0 4] [0 3]]`

First element of each nested list is the key and the second element of the nested lists is the value.

In prolog, implement a predicate, count by `cat/2`, that takes such a list as input and yields a two element list where:

- the first element is the sum of the values of all nested lists with `0` as the key,
  and
- the second element is the sum of the values of all nested lists with `1` as the key.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that **without swipl** you mean with standard prolog.
I used gnu prolog `v1.5.0` to check my answer which [follows the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20123925/3233599).

You start first by your base case a `0` for summation. then you check
each condition. for `0` you add to `Sum_0` and for `1` you add to `Sum_1`.
and that hold for the rest of the list `Tail` .

```
cat([],[0,0]). 

cat([[0,Value]|Tail],[Sum_0,Sum_1]):-
    Sum_0 is Value + Sum0,
    cat(Tail,[Sum0,Sum_1]).

cat([[1,Value]|Tail],[Sum_0,Sum_1]):-
    Sum_1 is Value + Sum1,
    cat(Tail,[Sum_0,Sum1]).
```

**Note:** you can use `#=` instead of `is` to make the predicate more [pure](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/purity), you will need to add `:- use_module(library(clpfd)).` to import `clpfd`.

Comment: What would you write to test your code?

Comment: `cat([[0,1],[0,3],[1,5],[1,6]],X)` and output is `X = [4, 11]` and your example is `cat([[0,1],[1,2],[1,3],[0,4],[0,3]],X).` and it's output is `X = [8, 5].`